# How to define a global Tag for OpenAPI 3 Spring Doc

Tags: spring-boot, springdoc

I'm using spring-doc to generate open api docs however by default it uses the controller name for tag. I know I can overwrite it with `@Tag` annotation but is there a way to do it globally for all controllers rather than defining the tag on each of them one by one especially since I want all of them to tagged with the project name?

Comment: Do your controllers span multiple classes? Can you share an image of what is the exact output you're getting as of now? Also, sharing a sample controller/class (similar to what you) have would help in highlighting how you're currently doing it.

Comment: Yes, it does! I have multiple controllers for different use cases and want all of them to have a same tag because I then use the docs to generate clients for other services.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but I expect that you would need to do that programmatically using [OpenAPIDefinition.tags()](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v2.0.0-RC3/apidocs/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/OpenAPIDefinition.html#tags). At least the documentation on the interface [Tag](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v2.0.0-RC3/apidocs/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/tags/Tag.html) states the following:

> It can also be used in OpenAPIDefinition.tags() to define spec level tags.